# How to count # of cases happened in last year for each row in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The question is, for each row in the same group, counting the number of cases which had been done within last year of the current row.

**The dataset (df) looks like:**

```
ID         Date    
abc      07/12/16    
abc      02/04/17   
abc      02/13/17    
abc      02/16/19    
xyz      11/03/14  
xyz      11/06/14    
xyz      02/17/16
```

My thought: first create a column lastyr: df['date'] - timedelta(days=365);
then compare each row with the whole group, count how many date in the group >= lastyr and < df['date']

**I tried to define a function in python like:**

```py
# Create the dataframe
d = {'ID': ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz'], 
     'Date': ['07/12/16', '02/04/17', '02/13/17', '02/16/19', '11/03/14', '11/06/14', '02/17/16']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df_1 = df 
# df_1 is same as df. I tried to compare each row in df to whole column in df_1.

# Define and apply the function
def lastyear(row):
    curr = row['Date']
    lastyr = curr - datetime.timedelta(days=365)
    if df['ID'] == df_1['ID']: # The compare is for same ID.
        return (df_1['Date'] < curr) & (df_1['Date'] >= lastyr)

df.apply(lastyear, axis=1).groupby(['ID']).count()
```

However it returns all false value. I think it's because it still compares each row in two dataframes, but I don't konw how to rewrite it as to compare each row to the whole column.

**The desired output would be:**

```
Group      Date       Count # of cases happened in last year

abc      07/12/16              0
abc      02/04/17              1
abc      02/13/17              2
abc      02/16/19              0
xyz      11/03/14              0
xyz      11/06/14              1
xyz      02/17/16              0
```

Comment: so all values from same group whose date is less than 365 days away?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this is my answer:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['delta'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff().dt.days
df['flag'] = (df.groupby('ID').delta.cumsum()<365).astype(int)
group_ids = df.flag.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
df['count'] = df['flag'].groupby([df['ID'], group_ids]).cumsum()
```

Result: (dropping irrelevant columns)

```
    ID       Date  count
0  abc 2016-07-12      0
1  abc 2017-02-04      1
2  abc 2017-02-13      2
3  abc 2019-02-16      0
4  xyz 2014-11-03      0
5  xyz 2014-11-06      1
6  xyz 2016-02-17      0
```

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your logic with slightly modified code:

```
....
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

def lastyear(row):
    curr = row.Date
    lastyr = curr - pd.Timedelta(days=365)
    return (df[(df.ID == row.ID) & (df.Date > lastyr) & (df.Date < curr)]).ID.size

df['Count'] = df.apply(lastyear, axis=1)
df
#Out[79]: 
#    ID       Date  Count
#0  abc 2016-07-12      0
#1  abc 2017-02-04      1
#2  abc 2017-02-13      2
#3  abc 2019-02-16      0
#4  xyz 2014-11-03      0
#5  xyz 2014-11-06      1
#6  xyz 2016-02-17      0
```

Comment: Thanks for modifing the code. It works!! However, when I try to apply it to my original dataset with around 300,000 rows, it runs pretty slowly. I'm wondering if there is a way to optimize the code and improve the runing time?

Comment: @Winnie Pandas' `df.apply` is basically iterating rows/columns which is slow. To get better performance, it's always better to look for vectorization Pandas/Numpy methods(you might check Yuca's solution) or go for Cython: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html